# Is there a way that downstream project can monitor upstream project build and only then it should build itself in multiproject pipeline

Tags: gitlab, microservices, cicd

For implementing multi project pipeline in gitlab, E.g the project structure is -

common-lib->deployment-lib->Microservice1
Microservice2
MicroserviceN
Incase of N no. of microservices, it would be tedious to update gitlab-ci.yaml file of common-lib.
So, the better way is to only build the services whenever the common-lib is built.
Is there a way in multi project pipeline, that I can restrict the trigger present in deployment-lib to start only if common-lib is built.
Also, any better suggestions for avoiding redundant builds of unnecessary microservices since the count is high.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [pipeline subcriptions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html#trigger-a-pipeline-when-an-upstream-project-is-rebuilt) allow you to subscribe to upstream builds from downstream projects.

Comment: Thanks @sytech, but I work on a private subgroup where the upstream project lies. Subscriptions pre-requisite needs public upstreams. Please suggest any other work-around though this was a good option.